# Best way to manage my own paths in Google Maps Android API

Tags: java, android

I have to do a mobile application which will have my own paths that i have to put in the map, what is the best way to manage the paths? KML files with the paths and upload them to the map or a specific database for that purpose?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as too broad. "What is the best way to..." is not a popular type of question. Recommend rewording to try make it more specific.

Comment: paths?? just out of interest, what do you mean by that. Draw on the Map?

Comment: You could just store the source and destination points in SQLite, and use the directions API to draw the paths, see here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32940175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm using a simple SQLite database for that and it works fine, first I save the locations as real types in the database and then I can save the locations on a list of LatLgn objects or on a hashmap with String key and Marker object, for example:

private void getLatLgns()    {

```
    DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection(this, "MapsDB", null, 1); 
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbc.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Latitude,Longitude from Records", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){ 
        do {
            allLatLng.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(0)), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(1))));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}
```

private void addingMarkers {

```
for (int x= 0; x < allLatLng.size() ; x++) {
        hashMarkers.put(String.valueOf(x), mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(allLatLng.get(x)));
        Log.d("Position:", x + " " + allLatLng.get(x).latitude + " " + allLatLng.get(x).longitude);
    }
```

}