# how to draw a route with google maps api in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to draw a route using the google maps api, currently I can send the request to the google server and get the full json with the route.

Is there a method that I can implement to draw the route in the map using this json?

Also, is there an object in the api that can be instantiated with the route obtained from the json?

Comment: You need to decode the base64 encoded points, and draw the polyline, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32940175/4409409

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial for a better insight http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/